# "This view is read-only" in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: windows-10, python, intellij-idea

I hope this is the correct Stack for this question.

I use IntelliJ IDEA to develop Python code and use the iPython support. Often times I switch between editor and console. Often times, the cursor is not at the currently active line and I get the warning as shown below when pressing for example <kbd>enter</kbd>. How can I ensure the cursor is moved to the active line automatically?

[image: This view is read-only in the IntelliJ Python console]

Comment: Found 2 workarounds which might relate here : (1) Turn vim emulator OFF (cmd+shift+A, and type 'vim'), (2) Disabling all log highlight plugins (i.e. Ideolog).

Comment: Thanks but I'm running an almost stock version without these plugins installed.

Comment: Try to disable all plugins (low chance of this being helpful). Some people downgraded to previous versions to avoid this problem.

Comment: Good to know I'm not alone. Te only downloaded plugin I have enabled is the  Python one  so that probably won't give much. Also downgrading isn't supported on this company laptop :(

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in IntelliJ. You might want to leave a comment in the issue tracker with reproducible steps: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-25764/This-view-is-read-only-in-debugger-console

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).